# Click link and show 3 values on page from datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i have bunch of records in Datatables.

i have a 4th button which is being used as Action. it do nothing for now just show a pop up. 
what i want to do is, when i click on one of the action button, then i want the adjacent three values to show on same page at down or up somewhere. for example if we consider first row and click on its action then i want CameraIP ,PORT and URL values to show on bottom, same for every row. CLICK on action and SHOW Adjacent three values.
I dont know how its possible in Datatables to judge that on which action we have clicked and which value should be passed. any help will be appreciated

[image: Datatables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give all action button a class `btnAction` and then use this:

```
    $(".btnAction").on("click",function(){
      var value1=$(this).parents("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
      var value2=$(this).parents("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
      var value3=$(this).parents("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
      alert(value1+"  "+value2+"   "+value3);
    });
```

You can then do anything with `value1`, `value2` and `value3` to show them anywhere on the page. For instance, you can put a blank div on html page with id `tblValues` and then change the `alert(value1+"  "+value2+"   "+value3);` line to this:

```
   $("#tblValues").html(value1+"  "+value2+"  "+value3);
```